# Android images to fill available width with correct height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I am trying to create a recycler view item to show multiple rows of multiple images side-by-side:

- [image 1] [image 2] [image 3]
- [image 4] [image 5] [image 6]
- [image 7] [image 8] [image 9]

I want to avoid setting any width or height as I want the images to scale to fill the available width of the screen. I am trying to do this with purely Android layout XML (ie. would rather not do it programmatically if possible) and want to avoid setting a fixed height. However I cannot find any applicable height settings to achieve this.

The Stack Overflow topics always I find tend to suggest `layout_weight`, which 'almost works' as the images do fill the available width, however the height of the wrapper is too big and it is still the height of the original images.

See in the image below, the **blue line** shows the height of the container, which gives the appearance of a lot of unintentional margin/padding.

Is it possible to amend the following to also trim the height of the wrapper to fit the images more accurately?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/card_ha" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/card_ha" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/card_ha" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

[image]

Comment: May be android:scaleType="centerCrop" for ImageView ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Nice suggestion Style-7, but tried all of the `scaleType` values and no good.

Comment: I did it, but programmatically only by override method onWindowsFocusChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `adjustViewBounds`?

See, As per the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) and my usage experience as well, `adJustViewBounds` does the job from xml to adjust the `ImageView's` bounds/borders according to the ratio of the image/drawable as also mentioned in the image attached below.

[image]

So, if you set the `width` to `0dp` and `height` to `wrap_content` which you've already done, ImageView's size will adjust as per the aspect ratio.

**To do it:** Add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in the all of the `ImageViews` tags. You don't have to do anything else programmatically or in xml.

Also, I would suggest using [`GridView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView) if you're thinking of adding more rows of images, otherwise no need.

Comment: You are a legend. I was sure there must be a 'one-liner' way to do this! I will also check out the GridView, thanks!

Comment: @JosephMcDermott I'm glad it helped. You're welcome. And You need `GridView` because for a 2d array type structure as you've shown at the beginning of your question, `GridView` is the key, pass it a single `ImageView` layout and max number of views in a single row (3-4 optimally) and it will populate the 2d structure. Also, you can further make Gallery/Photos like structure with increasing/decreasing the views through pinch zoom gesture.